# Consulta lenta 100% cpu

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un problema cuando ejecuto la paginación se pone lento debió a la consulta llega a 100% cpu.

```
SELECT id, nombre, precio FROM skinShop WHERE descripcion='premium' AND 
nombre NOT IN (SELECT item_id FROM compras WHERE user_id = '$id_s') ORDER 
BY precio + 0  ASC, nombre ASC LIMIT
```

Este es el script completo: de paginación:

```
if(isset($_POST["page"])){
    $page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); //filter number
    if(!is_numeric($page_number)){die('Invalid page number!');} //incase of invalid page number
}else{
    $page_number = 1; //if there's no page number, set it to 1
}
//get total number of records from database for pagination
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM skinShop WHERE descripcion='premium' AND nombre NOT IN (SELECT item_id FROM compras WHERE user_id = '$id_s') ORDER BY precio + 0  ASC, nombre ASC");
$get_total_rows = $results->fetch_row(); //hold total records in variable
//break records into pages
$total_pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page);
//get starting position to fetch the records
$page_position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);
//Limit our results within a specified range. 
$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, nombre, precio FROM skinShop WHERE descripcion='premium' AND nombre NOT IN (SELECT item_id FROM compras WHERE user_id = '$id_s') ORDER BY precio + 0  ASC, nombre ASC LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page");
$results->execute(); //Execute prepared Query
$results->bind_result($id, $nombre, $precio); //bind variables to prepared statement
//Display records fetched from database.
echo '<div class="row" style="display: -webkit-inline-box;">';
```

Que puedo hacer por que la verdad tengo días en buscar una solución. Espero me den una mano. Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Podrías por favor explicar lo que intentas hacer para que entendamos?  ¿Por qué le sumas `0` a `precio`?  ¿Qué hace un `LIMIT` sin valor en la consulta? ¿Tus tablas están indexadas? ¿Están relacionadas?  Si lo están, ¿por qué no haces una sola consulta usando `JOIN` para unir las tablas en vez de hacer varias consultas y dentro de ellas otras sub-consultas? ¿Por qué usas **falsas consultas preparadas**?

Comment: Es una tienda que tengo el problema es que en la paginacion cuando le doy siguiente pagina se demora en cargar salta 100% cpu. 

La idea es que no muestre lo que ya tengo comprado en la consulta, por eso puse el not in con una subconsulta pero eso sobrecarga. 

En pocas palabras esa consulta que vez como lo convertiria en left join o solamente join.